# using # in rails routes..!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to have a routing rule which does the below

`http://localhost:3003/tab/show#user11`

when this url is loaded, the system should fetch the value after # and use it to generate user output.

I tried to add this rule in the routes.rb file

```
 match "tab/show#:value => "tab#show"
```

but i could not able to use this and fetch the value after # like

```
@current = request["value"]
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of url isn't being sent to the server during request. So, naturally, you can't get access to it on the server-side. Use javascript to access it.

And it's not Rails' "feature". It's common thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your root to

```
match "tab/show/:value => "tab#show"
```

and use the URL

```
http://localhost:3003/tab/show/user11
```

then it will be available in the params hash:

```
@current = params[:value]
```

Unless you have a good reason for your current structure then this is the best way to do it.

Tom